# sorting array with certain values?

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

This is an output array pushed from mysql query

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 7
            [CategoryName] => Test it
            [Parent] => 2
            [Thumb] => 4
            [sort] => 0
            [MediaID] => 4
            [MediaTitle] => asd
            [MediaName] => 1349012691_4.jpg
            [MediaType] => image
            [MediaSize] => 369848
            [UploadTime] => 1349012691
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 8
            [CategoryName] => Test all
            [Parent] => 4
            [Thumb] => 5
            [sort] => 0
            [MediaID] => 5
            [MediaTitle] => asaas
            [MediaName] => 1349012728_9.jpg
            [MediaType] => image
            [MediaSize] => 416817
            [UploadTime] => 1349012728
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Test Image
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 2
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 2
            [CategoryName] => Test Sub
            [Parent] => 1
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 4
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 3
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 6
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 1
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 8
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 5
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 10
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 6
            [CategoryName] => Test Remove
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 12
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

)
```

I need to sort this array so it show Parents Category First then child categories.

I need the output something like

```
Array
(

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Test Image
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 2
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )
        //sub category
            [1] => Array
            (
                [CategoryID] => 8
                [CategoryName] => Test all
                [Parent] => 4
                [Thumb] => 5
                [sort] => 0
                [MediaID] => 5
                [MediaTitle] => asaas
                [MediaName] => 1349012728_9.jpg
                [MediaType] => image
                [MediaSize] => 416817
                [UploadTime] => 1349012728
            )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 2
            [CategoryName] => Test Sub
            [Parent] => 1
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 4
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )
                //sub category
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [CategoryID] => 7
                    [CategoryName] => Test it
                    [Parent] => 2
                    [Thumb] => 4
                    [sort] => 0
                    [MediaID] => 4
                    [MediaTitle] => asd
                    [MediaName] => 1349012691_4.jpg
                    [MediaType] => image
                    [MediaSize] => 369848
                    [UploadTime] => 1349012691
                )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 3
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 6
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 1
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 8
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 5
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 10
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 6
            [CategoryName] => Test Remove
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 12
            [MediaID] => 
            [MediaTitle] => 
            [MediaName] => 
            [MediaType] => 
            [MediaSize] => 
            [UploadTime] => 
        )

)
```

Can I do this with PHP?

Comment: This is not sorting but grouping based on parent id .. Please correct me if am wrong ??

Comment: Sure you can, but if its wise?

Comment: @JvdBerg yes i think its wise because if i sort it i won't have to loop through 2 arrays to list Child Categories under Parents Category

Comment: @Baba may i miss the title but whatever i think the result will be the same :)

Comment: And what if your tree contains a million entries and is nested many levels deep, are you gonna fetch them all an sort them?

Comment: @JvdBerg there is not million entries at it all also i need this just for categories modifications not to list entries

Comment: The correct strategy for this kind of problems is to fetch the top leafs, and when a detail is needed only fetch that detail.

Comment: @Marco can i get the serialise version of the array so that i don't have to recreate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
# Short Version of your Array
$oldList = Array(
    "0" => Array("CategoryID" => 7,"CategoryName" => "Test it","Parent" => 2),
    "1" => Array("CategoryID" => 8,"CategoryName" => "Test all","Parent" => 4),
    "2" => Array("CategoryID" => 4,"CategoryName" => "Test Image","Parent" => 0),
    "3" => Array("CategoryID" => 2,"CategoryName" => "Test Sub","Parent" => 1),
    "4" => Array("CategoryID" => 3,"CategoryName" => "Test Category","Parent" => 0),
    "5" => Array("CategoryID" => 1,"CategoryName" => "Test Category","Parent" => 0),
    "6" => Array("CategoryID" => 5,"CategoryName" => "Test Category","Parent" => 0),
    "7" => Array("CategoryID" => 6,"CategoryName" => "Test Remove","Parent" => 0)
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(__group($oldList));
```

Function used

```
function __group($oldList)
{
    # Get Category Position
    $category = array_map(function($item) { return $item['CategoryID'];}  ,$oldList); 

    #Get Only Parent List and add to new list
    $newList = array_filter($oldList , function($item) {  return $item['Parent']  == 0 ; } );

    foreach($oldList as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value['Parent'] != 0) {
            # Mapt Chiled to parent using Parent ID & Category ID 
            $newList[array_search($value['Parent'],$category)]['child'][] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newList ;
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Test Image
            [Parent] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CategoryID] => 8
                            [CategoryName] => Test all
                            [Parent] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 3
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 1
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CategoryID] => 2
                            [CategoryName] => Test Sub
                            [Parent] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 5
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 6
            [CategoryName] => Test Remove
            [Parent] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CategoryID] => 7
                            [CategoryName] => Test it
                            [Parent] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will group entries as you want:

```
function groupData($data) {
    $tree = array();
    $waiting = array();
    $index = array();
    foreach ($data as &$entry) {
        $index[$entry['CategoryID']] = &$entry;
        if (isset($waiting[$entry['CategoryID']])) {
            $entry['children'] = &$waiting[$entry['CategoryID']];
        } else {
            $entry['children'] = array();
        }
        if ($entry['Parent']) {
            if (isset($index[$entry['Parent']])) {
                $index[$entry['Parent']]['children'][] = &$entry;
            } else {
                if (!isset($waiting[$entry['Parent']])) {
                    $waiting[$entry['Parent']] = array();
                }
                $waiting[$entry['Parent']][] = &$entry;
            }
        } else {
            $tree[] = &$entry;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

If you need also to sort results by 'sort' attribute, some name or anything else best would be to do that in your SQL query. Function above will not change records order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code bellow. This will group array and sort every array(root and child arrays) depending on sort key. To retrieve new grouped/sorted array use this $newArray = groupMe($originalArray);

```
function groupMe($array) {
    $returningArray = array();

    $mapCatIdCategory = array();
    //first pass create mapCatIdCategory
    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        $mapCatIdCategory[$item['CategoryId']] = &$item;
        $item['child'] = array();
    }

    //second pass is for setting child
    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        $parentId = $item['Parent'];
        if ($parentId == 0) {   //no parent category => add to root
            $returningArray[] = &$item;
        }
        else if (isset($mapCatIdCategory[$parentId])){ //not sure if data is always valid
            $mapCatIdCategory[$parentId]['child'][] = &$item; 
        }
    }

    //third pass sort root and all child array(recursively)
    recursiveSort($returningArray);

    return $returningArray;
}

function recursiveSort(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        if (count($item['child']) >  1) { //empty or 1 elements arrays are already sorted
            recursiveSort($item['child']); //sort child
        }
    }

    usort($array, "cmpCategory"); //sort array by user comparasion function
}

function cmpCategory($a, $b) {
    if ($a['sort'] == $b['sort']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['sort'] < $b['sort']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```